# How can I use an unbound field in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm working with a `DataGridView` having two `TextBoxColumn`s and a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`.

As *datasource* I bound a `DataTable` with three columns: *"ID"*, *"Name"*, *"Surname"*, but I need to show only the last two columns, so in my datagrid I defined only `Name` and `Surname` (and the button column) setting the `AutoGenerateColumns` property equal to `false`.

Now I need to use the *"ID"* field when the button on a row is clicked...

What's the correct way to get the *"ID"* value from the current row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide something `.Visible` do not works fast. Try to use `DataView` and `BindingSource`.

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx).

There are `filters` that works very good.
Like this:

```
 BindingSource tSource = new BindingSource();
 DataView view = new DataView(_table);
 tSource.DataSource = view;
```

Here I find a row:

```
 DataRow row = CurrentRow(_dataGridView);
```

Here is the Implementation:

```
 public static DataRow CurrentRow(DataGridView aGrid)
    {
        CurrencyManager xCM =
          (CurrencyManager)aGrid.BindingContext[aGrid.DataSource, aGrid.DataMember];
        DataRowView xDRV = (DataRowView)xCM.Current;
        return xDRV.Row;
    }
```

Something like this should work.

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

If it's about showing the other columns, I'd leave the ID column in, and hide it by setting `Columns["ID"].Visible` to false. Then you can just access the data in the column, but it doesn't show on screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridview.Rows[gridview.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["id"].Value
```

you will get "id" value of the current row

Comment: Will I get it even if it's not bound to the datagrid? Are you sure?

Comment: then you will get a null value

Comment: What I mean is that I don't have an "Id" column in my grid, so I think your solution should not work form me.

Comment: if your datasource contains id column then a new column will be created in grid with a system specified name i think you can get it by index of the column